# Faster reading of data using pandas.io.parsers.read_table

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a table into pandas.  The columns in the table are separated by (variable amounts of) whitespace and the file contains lines before and after the data table which must be skipped.  The table also can contain comments.  Currently I am using

```
data = pandas.io.parsers.read_table(filename, sep='\s+', delim_whitespace=True, 
           skiprows=nstart, skipfooter=nend, names=column_names, 
           comment='#')
```

where nstart and nend are the number of lines before and after the table and column_names are the names of the columns.  Unfortunately this invokes the python implmentation of the parser in pandas and is very slow--reading ~100000 lines takes 2s.  This is the bottleneck for the data processing (lots of files!) and unfortunately changing the output format isn't an option.

Is there any way to make this faster?

With some experimentation, I found that leaving out skipfooter and explicitly removing them from the data table is over 6x faster as pandas can (I think) then use the C parser:

```
data = pd.io.parsers.read_table(filename, delim_whitespace=True,               
           skipinitialspace=True, skiprows=nstart, names=column_names,  
           comment='#', error_bad_lines=False)           
data.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)                                      
footer = data.index >= data.shape[0] - nend                             
data.drop(data.index[footer], inplace=True)
```

However, this requires an additional reset_index call (because the index is set to NaN) and gives a warning:

```
DtypeWarning: Columns (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
```

If I set low_memory=True, pandas segmentation faults.  Using `dtype=numpy.float64` (all data is numeric) causes

```
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() > int()
```

either because of the footer lines or the comment lines.  If the warning could be removed, then this would be an acceptable solution.

Comment: you need to supply platform and pandas/numpy version information.

Comment: Sorry!  I'm using python 3.3.5, pandas 0.13.1 and numpy 1.8.0 on Arch Linux (64 bit, fully updated).  I see the same behaviour with python 2.7.6, except using dtype gives an AttributeError instead of a TypeError.